# Bash condition of the form - [ -n "${VAR:-x}" ] gets evaluated even though VAR is set

Tags: bash, syntax, shell, environment-variables

I have written an if statement of the form:

```
if [ -n "${VAR:-x}" ]; then
   #do something
   export VAR=#something
fi
```

My shell script calls this statement twice and **surprisingly** passes the condition twice.

[hint (perhaps...): This exact code is repeated in a function in an included file. The if statement is first evaluated prior to function invocation. It is "again" evaluated when the function is invoked.]

What is the matter here? Do I understand the -x flag incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the idea from:
http://fixunix.com/questions/15902-bash-checking-if-env-var-set.html 
and had been mislead. Perhaps this had been my bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${VAR:-x}` says if `VAR` is not set substitute the string `x` otherwise substitute the value of `VAR`.

Similarly, `${FOO:-bar}` says substitute the value of `FOO` or the string `bar` if `FOO` is not set [as described here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/ShellParameterExpansion.html).

This means `-n "${VAR:-x}"` will always be true as `-n` means check if not blank and `"${VAR:-x}"` will never be blank.

Comment: How then do I query a variable's existence/not-nullness?

Comment: Just -n "${VAR}" should do it.  This will be true if VAR is set and not blank.